# elasticsearch data_path remove one on elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have two path.data:
`path.data: ["/datassd/elasticsearch", "/data/elasticsearch"]`
but one is quite small and always full, I want to not use it anymore and to only use one.
is it possible to

- remove it from conf and restart ? If so, what will happen ? Will data be available and no more will be added so in some time I can get rid of it entirelry or may I lose data (I don't want that)
- can I do a dynamic update somewhere to force data to be writton only one one ?

Thanks for your help,  or any tips, it's easy to add one datapath but I can't find how to not use one.

Comment: what is the elasticsearch version?

Comment: @hamidbayat it's 7.9.2

Answer (score 1):

stop elasticsearch service

remove the small data.path config.

```
cp -r /datassd/elasticsearch/nodes/0/indices/*    /data/elasticsearch/nodes/0/indices/
```

start elasticsearch service

use dangling API and Import API to import indices again:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/dangling-indices-list.html
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/dangling-index-import.html